# Transform React class componennt into functional component

Tags: reactjs

i'm new in Reactjs and i am trying to convert a React class component into react hooks , with no success. When i use the class component everything in working , but when i try to use it with hooks method , there are some transformation i don't know how to deal with

This is the original class

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.scss";
import { Login, Register } from "./components/login/index";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLogginActive: true
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    //Add .right by default
    this.rightSide.classList.add("right");
  }

  changeState() {
    const { isLogginActive } = this.state;

    if (isLogginActive) {
      this.rightSide.classList.remove("right");
      this.rightSide.classList.add("left");
    } else {
      this.rightSide.classList.remove("left");
      this.rightSide.classList.add("right");
    }
    this.setState(prevState => ({ isLogginActive: !prevState.isLogginActive }));
  }

  render() {
    const { isLogginActive } = this.state;
    const current = isLogginActive ? "Register" : "Login";
    const currentActive = isLogginActive ? "login" : "register";
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="login">
          <div className="container" ref={ref => (this.container = ref)}>
            {isLogginActive && (
              <Login containerRef={ref => (this.current = ref)} />
            )}
            {!isLogginActive && (
              <Register containerRef={ref => (this.current = ref)} />
            )}
          </div>
          <RightSide
            current={current}
            currentActive={currentActive}
            containerRef={ref => (this.rightSide = ref)}
            onClick={this.changeState.bind(this)}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const RightSide = props => {
  return (
    <div
      className="right-side"
      ref={props.containerRef}
      onClick={props.onClick}
    >
      <div className="inner-container">
        <div className="text">{props.current}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

This is my transformed class

```
import React,{useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import {Login, Register} from './components/login/'

const  App = () => {

  const [isLogginActive, setLogginActive] = useState(true)

  useEffect(()=>{
    rightSide.classList.add("right")
  },[])
  /* console.log("Premierement")
  console.log({isLogginActive})
  setLogginActive(!{isLogginActive})
  console.log("Deuxiemement")
  console.log({isLogginActive}) */

  const changeState = (props)=>{
    if({isLogginActive}){
      rightSide.classList.remove("right");
      rightSide.classList.add("left");
    }else{
      rightSide.classList.remove("left");
      ightSide.classList.add("right");
    }
    setLogginActive(prevState =>({isLogginActive: !prevState.isLogginActive}))
  }

  const current = {isLogginActive} ? "Register":"Login";
  const currentActive = {isLogginActive} ? "login":"register"

  return (
    <div className="App">
        <div className="login">
          <div className="container" ref={ref => (container = ref)}>
            {isLogginActive && (
              <Login containerRef={ref => (current = ref)} />
            )}
            {!isLogginActive && (
              <Register containerRef={ref => (current = ref)} />
            )}
          </div>
          <RightSide
            current={current}
            currentActive={currentActive}
            containerRef={ref => (rightSide = ref)}
            onClick={changeState}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
  );
}

const RightSide = props => {
  return(
    <div
      className="right-side"
      ref={props.containerRef}
      onClick={props.onClick}
    >
      <div className="inner-container">
        <div className="text">{props.current}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

I don't put the login and register components .. i'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try without destructuring the state and modifying the setLogginActive as well. Something like this in functional component

```
  const changeState = (props)=>{
    if(isLogginActive){
      rightSide.classList.remove("right");
      rightSide.classList.add("left");
    }else{
      rightSide.classList.remove("left");
      rightSide.classList.add("right");
    }
    setLogginActive((prevState) =>!prevState)
  }

  const current = isLogginActive ? "Register":"Login";
  const currentActive = isLogginActive ? "login":"register"
```

Comment: ok i will try , but here the principal error i have is : 'rightSide' is not defined  no-undef

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do like this

```
const current = {isLogginActive} ? "Register":"Login";
const currentActive = {isLogginActive} ? "login":"register"
```

You have to put like this

```
const changeState = (props)=>{
    if(isLogginActive && rightSide){
      rightSide.classList.remove("right");
      rightSide.classList.add("left");
    }else{
      if(rightSide){
           rightSide.classList.remove("left");
           rightSide.classList.add("right");
      }
    }
    setLogginActive((prevState) =>!prevState)
  }
    const current = isLogginActive ? "Register":"Login";
    const currentActive = isLogginActive ? "login":"register"
```

Because it's not in the `return` it's an inside between the functional component.